# Pass parameter to stored procedure that can change the body of the query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to pass the parameter `@empActiveStatus` that can change the body of the query body before executing.

Note that the value of `@empActiveStatus` will change depending on what the user selects from the application, so `empActiveStatus` could be `empActive = 1` or `empActive = 0` or `(empActive = 1 or empActive = 0)`.

What I want to prevent is the creation of 3 stored procedures, but rather one and use the parameter to change the body of the query and what it returns.

Thanks in advance.

Scenario 1.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spcGetEmployees]
    @empID Int,
    @empActiveStatus varchar(50)
AS
    SELECT empLastName, empFirstName 
    FROM vwEmployees 
    WHERE empID = @empID AND empActive = 1  
GO
```

Scenario 2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spcGetEmployees]
    @empID Int,
    @scenarioActiveStatus varchar(50)
AS
    SELECT empLastName, empFirstName 
    FROM vwEmployees 
    WHERE empID = @empID AND empActive = 0
GO
```

Scenario 3:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spcGetEmployees]
    @empID Int,
    @scenarioActiveStatus varchar(50)
AS
    SELECT empLastName, empFirstName 
    FROM vwEmployees 
    WHERE empID = @empID AND (empActive = 1 OR empActive = 0) 
GO
```

Scenario 4: preferred procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spcGetEmployees]
    @empID Int,
    @scenarioActiveStatus varchar(50)
AS
    SELECT empLastName, empFirstName 
    FROM vwEmployees 
    WHERE empID = @empID AND @scenarioActiveStatus 
GO
```

Comment: And for **what** RDBMS is this supposed to be working?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are asking, but I think you are asking how to write a stored procedure that will accept a text value for the employee active status. Let's assume that the parameter `@empActiveStatus` could have the values 'Active' (this is `empActive` = 1), 'Inactive' (this is `empActive` = 0), or 'All' (this is any value of `empActive`). So the stored procedure would look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spcGetEmployees]
    @empID Int,
    @empActiveStatus varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT empLastName, empFirstName 
    FROM vwEmployees 
    WHERE empID = @empID 
    AND 
    CASE 
        WHEN @empActiveStatus = 'All' THEN 1 
        ELSE empActive END = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @empActiveStatus = 'All' THEN 1 
        ELSE  
            CASE WHEN @empActiveStatus = 'Active' THEN 1 
            WHEN @empActiveStatus = 'Inactive' THEN 0 
            ELSE -1 
         END 
    END
END;
GO
```

If the value for `@empActiveStatus` is 'All', we build a condition that says 1 = 1 to return all records regardless of that `empActive` value; otherwise, we use the value found in the `empActive` column and translate the values for `@empActiveStatus` to the appropriate values for the column.